# how to create a maven project in intellj with local archetype-catalog.xml

Tags: java, maven

when I create a maven project in intellj, and because of network intellj cannot get "archetype-catalog.xml" from "maven.apache.org". So I dowload it to ".m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetype\archetype-catalog\2.4" manually without choice and in the other hand I try to change the vm options like below:
[image]

The question is every time I create a new project this setting just gone. So do I just have to add the "-DarchetypeCatalog=local" every time? 
As you can see this is the 14th demo, how can I solve this problem? By the way If I use command line to generate new project it will generate a whole nice project with a /resources directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 0 : Intellij Specific

To setup that property as the default so that it gets picked up by all **new** projects :

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings

And then do the same thing (i.e. Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner). After this any projects created from this point on, will inherit that JVM arg.

The remaining options below are IDE agnostic.

---

**The following options are based on http://maven.apache.org/configure.html**

#### Option 1: Environment var MAVEN_OPTS

How about setting the following environment variable ?

`MAVEN_OPTS = "-DarchetypeCatalog=local"`

#### Option 2: Directly editing the shell script (shudder!)

The other would be to edit `mvn.bat` or `mvn.sh` directly to add that property in.

#### Option 3: Creating a `mavenrc` file

I noticed the following in v. 3.3.9 of the maven shell script:

```bash
 #
 # Optional ENV vars
 # -----------------
 #   M2_HOME - location of maven2's installed home dir
 #   MAVEN_OPTS - parameters passed to the Java VM when running Maven
 #     e.g. to debug Maven itself, use
 #       set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
 #   MAVEN_SKIP_RC - flag to disable loading of mavenrc files
 # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 if [ -z "$MAVEN_SKIP_RC" ] ; then

   if [ -f /etc/mavenrc ] ; then
     . /etc/mavenrc
   fi

   if [ -f "$HOME/.mavenrc" ] ; then
     . "$HOME/.mavenrc"
   fi

 fi
```

So you could put that property in either `/etc/mavenrc` or in `~/.mavenrc` and make sure that `MAVEN_SKIP_RC` is not set.

Comment: Solve it with your option 0.  You just saved my life. Thank you very much.